# Taking pictures secretly in the background with Phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova, android-camera, phonegap-plugins

Creating an app with PhoneGap and using the plugin camera of cordova, is there a way to take an automatic photo without opening the camera's view, and use the front camera (the one for selfies)?

Comment: Beyond the fact that this question is too broad, it smells of decitfulness. What function would require you to do this "secretly" without the user's consent?

Comment: No, I mean that the user doesn't see the camera view.. for exampe, he can see a button "take picture" and a picture is taken without open the camera screen

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Just wanted to check. I wasn't quite sure what the intention was behind this. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: No - indeed - thank you for gave me the opportunity to explain better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this plugin should help you, it doesn't open the camera preview.

https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview